# What is the Windows Phone 7.1 start screen tile margins?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to figure out what the default margins are for the WP7.1 start screen tiles, more specifically the exact positions of the top two tiles, from there I can figure out the rest. Also, I was wondering if setting these values explicitly when designing on a device with an aspect ratio of 480*800 would effect hwo this looked on a device with an aspect ratio of 340*480 (or whatever the new devices are)?

In addition, if anyone knows, do these margins change in WP8 since more tile sizes will be introduced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the emulator you can [make a screenshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg442300%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) and count the pixels:

[image: Screenshot]

**12 Pixels in between the tiles**

**28 pixels from the left to the first tile**

**93 Pixels from the top to the first tile**

As far as I know there is currently no information available about the new devices.

Comment: Excellent! and I agree I still havent downloaded VS 2012 or any Windows Phone 8 betas but when I figure it out I will post back!